# looping over multiple enums

Tags: c++, c++11

How would i loop over multiple enums.

I kind of want to have the enums inside skeleton

Not really sure on how to construct my enums to have them in a container like this

Then not really sure how i could loop it to get each of the types

Comment: @lubgr thats what i dont know how to do, its not set up right i want to be able to contain it all then loop everything, but need to be able to loop each enum by its self

Comment: @acraig5075 nothing like it, im trying to have enum inside enum kindof, i can already look a single enum, if it was not inside the skeleton namespace.

Comment: I smell a smell. A smelly smell.

Comment: @SimonC what???

Comment: The short answer is that you can't.   You can iterate over ranges of integral values, but the code in the loop will not be able to associate the integral values with values of an `enum` type.    Particularly since there is no guarantee that the enumerated values are unique - for example, there is nothing stopping `THIGH` and `HAND` (even if they are in distinct `enum` types) being associated with the same numeric value.

Comment: You might model this as a separate class that composes one or two containers.

Comment: @vahancho all ears

Answer (score 1):

I got a meta-programming approach based on tuple

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct foo_enumerator {

enum class foo {
    ONE = 0 ,
    TWO =  1,
    THREE = 2
};

static constexpr auto reflect = std::make_tuple(
                                            foo::ONE,
                                            foo::TWO,
                                            foo::THREE);

};

struct bar_enumerator {
    enum class bar {
        FOUR = 4,
        FIVE =  5,
        SIX = 6
    };

    static constexpr auto reflect = std::make_tuple(
                                            bar::FOUR,
                                            bar::FIVE,
                                            bar::SIX);

};

// a tuple for_each implementation
// can be replaced with something else, like boost hana for_each for example
namespace detail {

// workaround for default non-type template arguments
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;

// process the `From::value`-th element
template<typename FromIndex,
         typename ToIndex,
         typename Tuple,
         typename UnaryFunction>
struct for_each_t {
    constexpr UnaryFunction&& operator()(Tuple&& t, UnaryFunction&& f) const
    {
        std::forward<UnaryFunction>(f)(
                std::get<FromIndex::value>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)));
        return for_each_t<index_t<FromIndex::value + 1>,
                          ToIndex,
                          Tuple,
                          UnaryFunction>()(
                std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::forward<UnaryFunction>(f));
    }
};

// specialization for empty tuple-likes
template<typename FromIndex, typename Tuple, typename UnaryFunction>
struct for_each_t<FromIndex, index_t<0>, Tuple, UnaryFunction> {
    constexpr UnaryFunction&& operator()(Tuple&&, UnaryFunction&& f) const
    {
        return std::forward<UnaryFunction>(f);
    }
};

// specialization for last element
template<typename ToIndex, typename Tuple, typename UnaryFunction>
struct for_each_t<index_t<ToIndex::value - 1>, ToIndex, Tuple, UnaryFunction> {
    constexpr UnaryFunction&& operator()(Tuple&& t, UnaryFunction&& f) const
    {
        std::forward<UnaryFunction>(f)(
                std::get<ToIndex::value - 1>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)));
        return std::forward<UnaryFunction>(f);
    }
};

}  // namespace detail

template<typename Tuple, typename UnaryFunction>
constexpr UnaryFunction for_each(Tuple&& t, UnaryFunction&& f)
{
    return detail::for_each_t<detail::index_t<0>,
                              detail::index_t<std::tuple_size<
                                  std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>
                              >::value>,
                              Tuple,
                              UnaryFunction>()(
            std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::forward<UnaryFunction>(f));
}


int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{

    constexpr auto all = std::tuple_cat( foo_enumerator::reflect, bar_enumerator::reflect );

    for_each(all, [](auto e_value)  {
            std::cout << "Enumeration value: " << static_cast<unsigned int>(e_value) << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't. At least not in C++ (yet™).

To do what you're describing, you need reflections. Reflections allow you to go over objects at runtime in a dynamic fashion.

C#/.net provides this. Here's an example in C#.

```
enum MyEnum { Test, Test1, Test2, Another, One, Bites, The, Dust }
foreach (var value in typeof(MyEnum).GetEnumValues()) {
    WriteLine(value.ToString());
}
```

I'm not sure if C++ will ever adopt reflections, be it in this form or another.

Sorry if this isn't the be-all answer you were wishing for.