# Convert enum array to parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I am struggling with the creation of an object, because i have to create a new `parameter pack` from an array inside a function. The array contains a few `enum` elements of the same `enum` `type`.

The error message states, that the array is not static, thus not a valid input that could be converted into a parameter pack.

Is there a possibility to something as follows:

```
enum Enums{e1, e2};

template<typename T, auto ...Enums>
class Example{};

template<int size>
constexpr auto createObj(){

    Enums enum_array[size] = {};

    for(int i = 0; i< size ; i++){
        //fill array with e1 and e2
    }

    return Example<double, enum_array>();
}
```

Error message:

```
error: the address of ‘enum_array’ is not a valid template argument because it does not have static storage duration
return Example<double, enum_array>();
```

Comment: You cant use pointers to non-static local variables as template arguments, because the location of such variables aren't fixed at compilation time. There's probably some rule in the specification about this, but the technical reason is because of the location is not known.

Comment: It seems like you need the tuple, not an array. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56865208/looping-over-multiple-enums/56866296#56866296)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i see and thats why its possible to initialize static arrays and pass them as parameter packs.

Comment: @VictorGubin looks like i have to rewrite my code to tuples until C++23 has compile time reflections.

Comment: Templates _generate code_. If you just want an array that's going to be constant-folded, make the function `constexpr` and return an `std::array<Enum, 2>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need a few indirection level. First, to use any value as template parameter, it must be a compile time constant for the compiler to instanciate the template and generate its code.

For that, you'll need to put the function calculating the array in a constexpr function:

```
template<int size>
constexpr auto createObjArray() {
    auto enum_array = std::array<Enums, size>{};

    for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
        //fill array with e1 and e2
    }

    return enum_array;
}
```

Then, you'll need a way to expand the array into a pack. Right now in C++17 (and C++20) it cannot be done locally. You'll need an index sequence of some sort. The most straightforward way to do that is to use an helper function:

```
template<std::size_t... S>
constexpr auto createObjHelper(std::index_sequence<S...>){
    constexpr auto enumArray = createObjArray<sizeof...(S)>();

    return Example<double, enumArray[S]...>();
}
```

Then wrap all that from a single user facing function:

```
template<int size>
constexpr auto createObj(){
    return createObjHelper(std::make_index_sequence<size>());
}
```

---

Note that many of those helper function can be achieved using lambdas. For example, a lambda can have a constexpr body and be executed at compile time inside a runtime function:

```
template<std::size_t... S>
constexpr auto createObjHelper(std::index_sequence<S...>){
    //   implicitly constexpr ---v
    constexpr auto enumArray = []{
        auto enum_array = std::array<Enums, size>{};

        for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
            //fill array with e1 and e2
        }

        return enum_array;
    }();

    return Example<double, enumArray[S]...>();
}
```

And In C++20, you can use familiar template function syntax for lambda to avoid the helper function:

```
template<int size>
constexpr auto createObj(){
    //   implicitly constexpr ---v
    constexpr auto enumArray = []{
        Enums enum_array[size] = {};

        for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
            //fill array with e1 and e2
        }

        return enum_array;
    }();

    return []<std::size_t... S>(std::index_sequence<S...>) -> decltype(auto) {
        return Example<double, enumArray[S]...>();
    }(std::make_index_sequence<size>());
}
```

In C++23, if structured binding pack introduction is approved, then the second lambda can be removed in favor of creating a new pack directly in the function:

```
template<int size>
constexpr auto createObj(){
    //   implicitly constexpr ---v
    constexpr auto enumArray = []{
        Enums enum_array[size] = {};

        for(int i = 0; i < size ; i++){
            //fill array with e1 and e2
        }

        return enum_array;
    }();

    constexpr auto&& [...allEnums] = enumArray;

    return Example<double, allEnums...>();
}
```

Comment: i really appreciate your solution and you convinced me to use my old code. With C++23 i could rewrite everything to make it look better!